# Conversion of float to String is adding a lot of numbers

Tags: actionscript-3

```
var myNumber:Number = 1.8;

trace(myNumber);
```

The above gives "1.7999999999999998"

conversion of String(myNumber) also gives "1.7999999999999998"

This only happens with certain numbers. If (myNumber == 1.4) it doesn't give me this problem.

I've checked with the debugger and the values are correct both *before and after* the trace or String conversion. However, the string itself is incorrect.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See any of the many other questions about floating point. In short, there is no floating binary point number with the exact value or 1.8 (or 1.4).

Comment: odd I run that code and my output is "1.8"

Answer (score 0):

Due to the way floating point values are stored they rarely ever represent the exact value you put in. Read up on the way floating point values are stored if you are interested but you can solve your problem by rounding to the decimal place you would like to see outputted.